# Count how many words in a line of text? (in C Programming Language)

Tags: c

QUESTION:
What is wrong with this code example, what is missing?

**Current incorrect output is:**

There are 0 words in ""

---

**Code Explanation:**
Write a program that reads in a line of text, and prints out the number of words in that line of text. A word contains characters that are alphanumeric. Hint: Use the fgets() function.

**Sample run:**

**Input:**
from here to eternity 
**Output:**
4

**Input:**
start here and turn 180 degrees 
**Output:**
6

Code Snippet:
https://onlinegdb.com/H1rBwB83V

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 100

int countWords(char str[])
{
    int i=0;
    int count = 0;
    bool flag = false;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (isalnum(str[i]))
        {
            if (!flag)
            {
                count++;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        else
            flag = false;

        i++;
    }

    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char str[MAXLEN];
    int count;

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        str[strlen(str-1)] = '\0'; // the last character is the newline. replace with null
        count = countWords(str);
        printf("There are %d words in \"%s\"\n", count, str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Similar Tutorial:
https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-count-words-in-sentence/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error here:

```
str[strlen (str - 1)] = '\0';   // the last character is the newline. replace with null
```

Using the pointer `str - 1` leads to undefined behavior, as it points to memory outside the original string.

You actually meant to do this:  `strlen(str) - 1`  (notice the `-1` is moved outside the parentheses)

Comment: `str[strlen(str) - 1]` is a hackable exploit - consider if the the first character read was a _null character_. Also wrong if a `'\n'` was not read.  Consider `str[strcspn("\n")] = '\0';`